# trouble with avg SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is not giving me the correct results.  I'm trying to get the average status of a city in the following table:

```
    SNO         SNAME                   STATUS      CITY
    s1          Smith                   20          London         
    s2          Jones                   10          Paris          
    s3          Blake                   30          Paris          
    s4          Clark                   20          London         
    s5          Adams                   30          Athens
```

The query should return the average city status for all the cities.  I know the results should be 26.667, but as it is, my select statement is not working.  Here it is:

```
select avg(rs1.status) as average
from rs rs1, rs rs2
where rs1.city=rs2.city;
```

And the results I get:

```
        AVERAGE
---------------
    21.11111111
```

What am I forgetting???  Or do I not need to do a self join?

CODE TO CREATE TABLE:

```
create table rs
( sno    char(5)  not null,
  sname  char(20) not null,
  status smallint,
  city   char(15),
  primary key (sno)
);

insert into rs (sno, sname, status,city)
values('s1', 'Smith', 20, 'London');
insert into rs
values('s2', 'Jones', 10, 'Paris');
insert into rs
values('s3', 'Blake', 30, 'Paris');
insert into rs
values('s4', 'Clark', 20, 'London');
insert into rs
values('s5', 'Adams', 30, 'Athens');
```

Comment: Why would you self join?

Comment: Honestly, I thought it would be the only way to compare cities and then show status avg based on the city.  It's not as simple as a select avg(status) from rs query, there's more to it, I just can't figure out what...

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting 26.6667. Could you explain a bit perhaps?

Comment: I wish I could because it doesn't make sense to me.  That's just the figure I've been given.

Comment: @Bryan Oh okay, I see xD Seem's like we're all lost in a deep deep fog then :(

Comment: @Bryan Could the average be 36.6667 by any chance instead?

Comment: Looks like the answer given by user2722968 is the right one.  Not sure why the question wasn't worded clearly.  Thanks for your efforts, in any case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing that the original question is "what is the maximum(!) status of each city on average over all cities?":

```
SELECT AVG(m.mstatus)
FROM (SELECT MAX(status) AS mstatus
      FROM rs
      GROUP BY city) AS m
```

Given your example data, the result is `26.66666...`

Comment: Yes, that is probably the correct way of wording the question.  This is what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Way to go detective! Answers an unknown question.